# What is the difference between : int a = (b<<2) >>2; and int a = b & 0x3F; when b is an unsigned char?

Tags: c

i find a strange case:
when b=0x40 which is 64,

`int a = b & 0x3F` 
output is 0

`int a = (b<<2) >> 2` 
output is 64.
WHY IT IS 64?

1000 0000 << 2 = 0000 0000 and it should be 0?

I asked gpt and it runs them on the python, which turns out 64 again. I dont know why.

Comment: Bitwise shift operators perform integer promotion first

Comment: `(b<<2)` becomes `(64<<2)` by value conversion and integer promotion, which becomes `256`. `(256) >> 2` becomes 64.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be `0`? You should at least include all relevant information into your question, like the type of `b`.

Comment: Try something like  `unsigned char b = 64, c = 2; unsigned char a = (b << c) >> c;`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why do you think that would make a difference?

Comment: @interjay. I don't have a computer in front of me right now and I'm checking to see if the right operand is the driver for the type

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is not. Integer promotion is applied to both operands

Comment: Besides `&` being more correct (assuming you want to clear the 2 MSb), I find it more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All integer arithmetic in C is done in the `int` type or wider. Any operand narrower than an `int` is automatically either promoted to `int` or converted to an even wider type to match another operand.

In `b<<2`, the `unsigned char` `b` is automatically promoted to `int` before the shift. Then shifting 64 left two bits produces 256, an `int` value. Shifting it right two bits produces 64, and that is used to initialize `a`.

If you want an `unsigned char` value from the left shift, use a cast to convert the `int` result to `unsigned char`:

```
int a = (unsigned char) (b << 2) >> 2;
```

Comment: I thought it was promotion to the type of the right operand. What does `unsigned char b = 64, c = 2; unsigned char a = (b << c) >> c;` yield?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The bitwise shift operands promote each operand separately, per C 2018 6.5.7 3.

Comment: @MadPhysicist no, you are wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Thanks. TIL

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! I probably get it.
When it is promoted to int, b is no longer restricted to 8 digit length, so the left most two digit will not disappear as i wish. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits.

`b` is promoted to integer first. `0x40` doesn't change when promoted to integer, so `0x40 & 0x3f = 0`.

With `b` promoted to integer `0x40 << 2 = 0x100`, then `0x100 >> 2 = 0x40 = 64`.

Please note that logical operations on signed values in C could lead to `undefined behavior`. In this case the value is positive in which case **generally** (not always) the result is correct.

Comment: @Gerhardh an `int` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Maybe but `0x40<<2` is not `0x80`. Size of `int` doesn't really matter as it is always at least 16 bits.

Comment: @Gerhardh, yes, but seen the result it is reasonably 16 bits. Don't you agree?

Comment: Re “we have to assume that in your system the `int` type is at least 16bits”: The C standard requires an `int` to be at least 16 bits because C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1 requires `INT_MAX` to be at least 32767. Re “an `int` is 2 bytes”: The C standard does not specify that an `int` is two bytes. It does not specify the width of a byte except that it must be at least eight bits. A C implementation may define a byte to be 16 or 32 bits or other widths.

Comment: Re “In this case the value is positive in which case **generally** (not always) the result is correct”: The C standard fully defines the behavior for left shifts and right shifts of nonnegative values that do not overflow. It allows implementation-defined behavior or undefined behavior only for right shifts of negative values (implementation-defined) and left shifts of negative values or that overflow (undefined).

Comment: I never questioned your result. Only your intermediate value was wrong.

Comment: To be clear, `int` being larger than 16 bits isn't just theoretical. `int` is very commonly 32 bits. It's 32 bits in x86 and x86-64 environments.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes I have seen. Thank you.

Comment: Rolled back edit. An `int` is at least 16 bits. You misunderstood what the other Eric wrote.

Answer (score 0):

1. `0x40 & 0x3f == 0`
2. `0x40` is promoted to `int` which is larger than one byte (it has to be at least 16bits long). Because of that `(0x40 << 2) >> 2` does nothing.

Comment: Why does it get promoted?

Comment: @MadPhysicist because it is how C works (C standard). Most integer operations are done on `int`s

Comment: You should probably add that to your answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually, when C is to perform an operation having two operands and have to guess out the type to use, it won't choose the first encountered one but the "most precise" of both the operands. Without any specific cast, the constant "2" is assumed to be "int", thus the promotion.

Answer (score -3):

& is also a bitwise multiplication

b = 0100 0000
0x3f = 0011 1111

As you can see, multiplying bitwise you really get 0

In the second case - a = (b<<2) >> 2
this is equivalent to first multiplying the number twice by 2 and then dividing the number twice by 2, which in the end will give the same number.

A separate case is if the value of variable b is equal to the value of the shift (for example, if the number was uint32_t ans shift value if 32). A shift by the length of a number is an undefined behavior, at least for the C language, which is incidentally described in the standard (See section 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators of the C standard from 1999). And as [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) noticed in the comments "per C 2018 6.5.7 3, the integer promotions are applied to the operands of a shift. Therefore, all operation on the value is done with the width of at least int, not with the width (or length) of the operand, unless the operand is wider than int."
And the result is determined by the compiler that you use, in particular for gcc:
a << sizeof(a) = a

python uses big numbers for itself, so you don't have to be afraid of that there

1000 0000 << 2 = 0000 0000 ?
The correct answer is
1000 0000 << 2 = 10 0000 0000, if (1000 0000) is a bit representation
, but keep in mind that if 10 0000 0000 does not fit into a variable, then the program will cut it to the length of the variable (again, for example, if the number was uint8_t)

Comment: `&` is not a multiplication. Multiplying and dividing will give the same number only if there is no overflow after multiplying. The size of of the variable is in bytes, not bits. Shifting by 2 bits is perfectly fine. Nothing undefined here. Where did you get these statements?

Comment: @Gerhardh: `&` is indeed a bitwise multiplication. (Taking a[i] as the string of bits of some number A and b[i] as the string of bits of B, `A&B` produces C where the string of bits of C has c[i] = a[i]•b[i].) The rest of this answer is out of whack.

Comment: @Gerhard you have already been answered about bit multiplication, regarding the shift, I am really wrong, confusing both the bitwise and bytewise shift, I apologize, I edited my answer to not confuse anyone. However, in the case when the shift occurs by an amount greater than or equal to the length of the variable, undefined behavior still occurs, I just wanted to warn you, since it is not obvious.

Comment: Re ”in the case when the shift occurs by an amount greater than or equal to the length of the variable, undefined behavior still occurs”: This is not correct. Per C 2018 6.5.7 3, the integer promotions are applied to the operands of a shift. Therefore, all operation on the value is done with the width of at least `int`, not with the width (or length) of the operand, unless the operand is wider than `int`. (Technically has greater rank rather than wider, but effectively the same.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil well, didnt know that, thank you for the comment, edited my answer (once again).